# Unmark review as spam/abuse in Chrome Web Store

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I recently marked a few negative comments on my Chrome extension as spam/abuse, because I thought they were invalid, alarmist, and non-constructive. I realize now that I should have simply marked them as not helpful. Is it possible to unmark them as spam so I can see them again? I accidentally had posted duplicate replies to the comments which I want to delete, but I cannot see those either.

Is there some dev console code I could use to reveal the hidden comments?

I was directed from the Chrome Help Forum to this Stack Overflow tag to get help from the Chrome Web Store team itself.

Comment: I submitted a support request on the Chrome Web Store Help page, and they got back to me quickly saying that they would unhide the comments.    https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/contact/developer_support/?hl=en    I really wish this support link was easier to find. I couldn't find it on Google after extensive search, until I posted for help in the Chrome support forums. But it does exist, and apparently they do check it.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by [@V.Rubinetti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2180570/v-rubinetti) in the comments above, I submitted an issue report to [**Chrome Web Store Help**](https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/contact/developer_support/?hl=en)

**Reply from Google Developer Support**:

```
---------- Forwarded message ---------
From: Developer Support <cws-developer-support@google.com>
Date: Wed, Sep 18, 2019 at 4:01 PM
Subject: RE:
To: (me)



        Hi,

        Thanks for reaching out. Unfortunately, once you click on "Mark as
        Spam or Abuse", there is no way to undo it. But please note that,
        only you cannot see it, other users can still see the comment.

        Let me know if you have any questions.



Cheers!
[...]
CWS Developer Support
```